# When is the value of "this" shifted by an offset?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I was wondering whether `assert( this != nullptr );` was a good idea in member functions and someone pointed out that it wouldn’t work if the value of `this` had been added an offset. In that case, instead of being 0, it would be something like 40, making the assert useless.

When does this happen though?

Comment: Isn't it undefined behaviour to call a function on a null-pointer?

Comment: If `this` was derived by indexing an array of objects, where the array basing pointer was null.

Comment: @jogojapan well `assert()` is actually used to debug bugs :)

Comment: I don't remember if it's undefined behaviour. But if it is, `assert` doesn't help.

Comment: It is UB, but assert *might* help in non-optimized debug build.

Comment: @jogojapan I'd say yes, because the member-access for member functions is resolved from `a->b` to `(*a).b`.

Comment: @jogojapan I think it is UB by the standard but I think such assert would still help. My rationale is: after `Foo::bar()` is compiled, it looks just like a C function `Foo_bar( Foo* this );`, so I am just checking a C function parameter.

Comment: @qdii I understand what you are saying. But _undefined behaviour_ means it is not defined what happens when you have such a call in your code. In particular, there is no guarantee that the point of the `assert` is ever reached. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-beha

Comment: Note this is probably ineffective for virtual functions.

Comment: If this is null then its instance was destroyed, now where is actually this stored? Maybe it is compiler specific? If memory for instance was released, then some other thread might occupy its address range, making this non null. This way you cannot rely on such assertion.

Comment: Optimizing compilers have a tendency to optimize on the assumption that undefined behavior does not occur. Dereferencing a null pointer is clearly undefined behavior, so `assert(this != NULL);` may well be optimized out altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple inheritance can cause an offset, skipping the extra v-table pointers in the object.  The generic name is "[this pointer adjustor thunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481548/why-do-we-need-this-pointer-adjustor-thunk)".

But you are helping too much.  Null references are *very* common bugs, the operating system already has an assert built-in for you.  Your program will stop with a segfault or access violation.  The diagnostic you'll get from the debugger is always good enough to tell you that the object pointer is null, you'll see a very low address.  Not just null, it works for MI cases as well.

Comment: +1 good point, Thanks for the "this pointer adjustor thunking" link.

Comment: I find this answer somewhat misleading. C++ isn't built on the assumption that it necessarily runs on a system that supports memory protection (or segmentation). Also, even if it does, a segmentation fault does not usually provide very good information. For the stack trace you need a core dump, which you may not get, depending on the circumstances of the crash. And for the stack trace to be useful, you need debug symbols. Finally, calling a member function on a null pointer is undefined behaviour. UB is not the same as a segmentation fault, even on a system with memory segmentation.

Answer (score 4):

`this` adjustment can happen only in classes that use multiple-inheritance. Here's a program that illustrates this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int n;
  void af() { cout << "this=" << this << endl; }
};

struct B {
  int m;
  void bf() { cout << "this=" << this << endl; }
};

struct C : A,B {
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  C* c = NULL;
  c->af();
  c->bf();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get this output:

```
this=0
this=0x4
```

That is: your `assert this != nullptr` will not catch the invocation of `c->bf()` where c is `nullptr` because the `this` of the `B` sub-object inside the `C` object is shifted by four bytes (due to the `A` sub-object).

Let's try to illustrate the layout of a `C` object:

```
0:  | n |
4:  | m |
```

the numbers on the left-hand-side are offsets from the object's beginning. So, at offset `0` we have the `A` sub-object (with its data member `n`). at offset `4` we have the `B` sub-objects (with its data member `m`).

The `this` of the entire object, as well as the `this` of the `A` sub-object both point at offset 0. However, when we want to refer to the `B` sub-object (when invoking a method defined by `B`) the `this` value need to be adjusted such that it points at the beginning of the `B` sub-object. Hence the +4.

Answer (score 1):

Note this is UB anyway.

Multiple inheritance can introduce an offset, depending on the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct wup
{
    int i;
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl;
    }
};

struct dup
{
    int j;
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl;
    }
};

struct s : wup, dup
{
    void foobar()
    {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
};

int main()
{
    s* p = nullptr;
    p->foobar();
}
```

Output on some version of clang++:

> 0
>   0x4

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5b9e3329f094b0d3968f9c86d3a2a319-bb452bed83d06e87c370fcabced7e96d)

---

Also note, as I pointed out in the comments to the OP, that this `assert` might not work for virtual function calls, as the vtable isn't initialized (if the compiler does a dynamic dispatch, i.e. doesn't optimize if it know the dynamic type of `*p`).

Comment: I'm curious - does clang optimize out `assert(this != NULL)`?

Comment: @Casey On which optimization level?

Comment: @Casey -O0, no (not the linked clang++ version).

Comment: Maximum is enough for me. I know clang does interesting things in other cases of undefined behavior. (I really need to get clang setup on my windows machine at home).

Comment: Actually looked at the link, didn't realize Coliru had clang.

Comment: @Casey -O3 also doesn't optimize it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a situation where it might happen:

```
struct A {
    void f()
    {
       // this assert will probably not fail
       assert(this!=nullptr);
    }
};

struct B {
    A a1;
    A a2;
};

static void g(B *bp)
{
    bp->a2.f(); // undefined behavior at this point, but many compilers will
                // treat bp as a pointer to address zero and add sizeof(A) to
                // the address and pass it as the this pointer to A::f().

}

int main(int,char**)
{
    g(nullptr); // oops passed null!
}
```

This is undefined behavior for C++ in general, but with some compilers, it might have the
consistent behavior of the `this` pointer having some small non-zero address inside `A::f()`.

Comment: Normally, I'd put the `assert` inside `g`, so the `assert` in `f` is just another layer of debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers typically implement multiple inheritance by storing the base objects sequentially in memory. If you had, e.g.:

```
struct bar {
  int x;
  int something();
};

struct baz {
  int y;
  int some_other_thing();
};

struct foo : public bar, public baz {};
```

The compiler will allocate `foo` and `bar` at the same address, and `baz` will be offset by `sizeof(bar)`. So, under some implementation, it's possible that `nullptr -> some_other_thing()` results in a non-null `this`.

[This example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c0840cc4b7baa531a41140578b159387-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852) demonstrates (assuming the result you get from the undefined behavior is the same one I did) the situation, and shows an `assert(this != nullptr)` failing to detect the case. (Credit to @DyP who I basically stole the example code from).

Answer (score -3):

I think its not that bad a idea to put assert, for example atleast it can catch see below example

```
class Test{
public:
void DoSomething() {
  std::cout << "Hello";
}
};

int main(int argc , char argv[]) {
Test* nullptr = 0;
 nullptr->DoSomething();
}
```

The above example will run without error, If more complex becomes difficult to debug  if that assert is absent.

I am trying to make a point that null this pointer can go unnoticed, and in complex situation becomes difficult to debug , I have faced this situation.

Comment: I don't see how you can assert that a program that unconditionally invokes undefined behavior "will run without error."

Comment: I think multiple inheritance will introduce an offset for functions inside (some of the) base classes.

Comment: The question is about when it will have an offset, so this doesn't answer it.

Comment: try @Casey before passing judgment

Comment: @interjayi I was trying to answer this "I was wondering whether assert( this != nullptr ); was a good idea in member functions"

Comment: @marcin_j Thanks , I am trying to make a point that null this pointer can go unnoticed , and in complex situation becomes difficult to debug , I have faced this situation.